# How to open virtual machines made in VMWare Player from VMWare Server

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, vmware-server

I made some virtual machines in VMWare Player. Then, when I installed VMWare Server, it said I had to uninstall VMWare Player. So how can I access those virtual machines from VMWare Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vmware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/overview.html) to convert VMs between differnt formats, including Player to Server.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Player can't "make" virtual machines.  You need VMware Workstation or VMware Server for that.

Anyway, you can tell VMware Server to import the VM by pointing it to the .vmx file inside the VM directory.

Comment: If Player can't make VMs, then what does it make?

Comment: Nothing. It can only "play" pre-made virtual machines.

Comment: It can make them now.